# Upvote a cited dup when its score is 0?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've been going through the duplicate queue. I noticed a fair number of the cited duplicates have 0 votes.

It seems to me that a question that is being cited as a duplicate is useful (the person who asked the duplicate question should surely find it useful), and cited duplicate should probably have at least 1 vote based on the citation alone.

Should question that are cited duplicates receive a honorary upvote?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the quality of the cited question. It's a shame when a well written question gets marked as a duplicate and the cited duplicate is written by a 3 year old.

Comment: Dupes have less to do with the question quality, than with the answers for the question.  Questions can easily be improved.